# How to read django autocomplete lights value to generate choices dynamically?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin, django-autocomplete-light

Hey i would like to get the value of django autocomplete light in the model form and generate choices for the next fields accordingly.

```
class GroupPropertiesForm(forms.ModelForm):
  <strike>fields['equipment_grade']: forms.ChoiceField(
            choices=[(o.id, str(o))
                     for o in GroupProperties.objects.all(group=???group???)]</strike>
 class Meta:
    model = GroupProperties
    fields = ('group', 'bells')
    widgets = {
        'group': autocomplete.ModelSelect2(
            url='groups-autocomplete')
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the correct way to implement this functionality,
autocomplete light will provide information as a forward for the next attribute as they have written [Django auto complete light documentation](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#filtering-results-based-on-the-value-of-other-fields-in-the-form)